# Difference between Arrays and 3 dots (Varargs) in java

Tags: java, arraylist

Need to figure out what is the difference between `...` and arrays in JAVA, also an array list.

It seems we can use both as unlimited, but `...` is rarely used.

Really appreciate any help you can.

Answer (score 142, accepted):

The three dots can only be used in a method argument, and are called 'varargs'. It means you can pass in an array of parameters without explicitly creating the array.

`private void method(String[] args) {}` is called like `method(new String[]{"first", "second"});`

`private void method(String... args) {}` is called like `method("first", "second");`

Comment: It's worth noting that the varargs are just sugar. The method actually takes an array, plain array. `method(String... args)` can be invoked as `method("first", "second")`, but it can just as well be invoked as `method(new String[]{"first", "second"})`.

Answer (score 18):

- An [array](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html) is a fixed length collection of objects. e.g. `new int[5];`
- An [`ArrayList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) is a variable length collection of objects. e.g. `new ArrayList<Integer>();`
- The `...` in [variadic functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_function) is a part of a method signature denoting an array of parameters. e.g. `public void printLines(String... lines)`

Answer (score 1):

In other words, method(String...) means passing a variable number of parameters to the method.

Comment: Or passing no parameter in case of a method with one parameter (Varargs) because they're optional. 
It's up to the developer to properly implement the method to handle having zero or more of them.