# difference between float... and float[]

Tags: java

I was wondering, is there a difference between:

```
public float curvePoint(float... v) {
```

and:

```
public float curvePoint(float[] v) {
```

They both seem the same for me, except in syntax.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3158730/java-3-dots-in-parameters

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2367398/what-is-the-ellipsis-for-in-this-method-signature

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11640507/difference-between-arrays-and-3-dots-in-java

Comment: Compare `curvePoint(float[] a, float[] b)` and `curvePoint(float... a, float... b)`.

Comment: Damn, why didn't I think of searching for 3-dots. I searched for ... and couldn't find anything.